# ChildBrowser on phonegap 2.2 and ios 6 (ipad) not working

Tags: cordova, ios6, phonegap-plugins, childbrowser

I'm trying to get ChildBrowser plugin work using phonegap 2.2 on iOS 6 and latest xCode. I followed official instructions in the plugin's github wiki/readme. It seems that the plugin is loading but when I call

window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('http://www.google.com',{ showLocationBar: true });

nothing happens!

Any clue? Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you just get the "Loading..." message make sure you're referencing the childbrowser.js that came with the Ios ChildBrowser Plugin and not the one for another platform like Android. If you're not getting anything make sure you have "ChildBrowser" -> "ChildBrowserCommand" in Cordova.plist and NOT "ChildBrowser" -> "ChildBrowser.js". Also, make sure your device ready event is getting fired, I once accidentally copied cordova-2.2.0.js from an android project over to IOS which caused all events to stop getting fired.

Answer (score 0):

There is an outstanding issue with iOS 6 for the ChildBrowser plugin.

You should be able to test to see if this is iOS6 specific. Run your app under an iOS5 simulator. If ChildBrowser works, then you know that you're hitting the iOS 6 specific problem.

A support issue has been opened, but I know of no solution yet...

https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/55

Answer (score 0):

1) use build.phonegap.com

2) add the config.xml with following under assets\www folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "com.phonegap.example"
    version   = "1.0.0">

<name>PhoneGap Build Application</name>

<description>
A simple PhoneGap Build application.
</description>

<author href="https://example.com" email="you@example.com">
Your Name
</author>
    <preference name="orientation"     value="portrait" />
<feature name="http://plugins.phonegap.com/ChildBrowser/2.0.1" />
<access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

3) remove all phonegap2.x.x.js and childbrowser2.x.x.js which is referred from that particular page where your using childbrowser features (like index.html) 
then simply add the following even though it is not in the folders (phonegap builder will use the updated version)

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="childbrowser.js"></script>
```

4) just put the following for testing

```
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#" onClick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('http://www.xyz.com')">Click here to open</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Hope for the best :)